# I can't change the height or text-align in navbar items

Tags: html, css

I'm really new to this whole CSS and HTML and i'm trying to make a simple navbar with what I have learned.
The problem is, I have the navbar items centered and I was happy with it. Then I decided to add this hover option so the background color of each item would change when hovering on it.

The issue is I cannot change the height or alignment of the boxes.

[weird box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P68bY.png)

```css
#header {
  background: #9842f5;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  font-family: Arial;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

nav ul:hover {
  background: blue;
  height: 20px important;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  opacity: 0.78;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<nav id="header">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Contact Info</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>NUKE</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Having three UL with one LI each makes little sense here to begin with - you want _one_ list, that contains three items. And `height` simply has no effect on `inline` elements.

Comment: It's better to use flexbox for such cases. I'm not sure what is the expected results though. Is it something like [that](https://jsbin.com/cufuqex/edit?html,css,output)?

Comment: @MoshFeu wow, thanks! That's exactly what I wanted, and I learned a lot as a beginner. I cannot thank you enough!

Comment: No problem @MohiReza :) Good luck with your coding journey!

Answer (score 1):

The hover effect should be added to the list-items (`<li>`). To get more space, you can add padding instead of changing the height.

Also, only add one `<ul>` instead of 3.

```css
#header {
  background: #9842f5;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
  font-family: Arial;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
nav li:hover{
  background: blue;
  
}
nav li {
  display: inline;
  opacity: 0.78;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="header">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Contact Info</li>
    <li>NUKE</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```